# Inheriting a class which is built using a static inner class Builder

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder-pattern

I have a `Class A` with quite a number of member variables. In order to make it immutable and validate the member variables during construction, I made its constructor private and used an inner public static builder class (`ClassABuilder`) to build it. (Joshua Bloch Effective Java, Item 2).

Now what I do not understand is, how other programmers will subclass `Class A` to implemet their own specific behavior. I read through the disadvantages of Builder Pattern from the book but did not see subclassing mentioned as one. Am I missing something? Is there an elegant way around this?

Making the constructor `protected` was one of my thoughts, but it would still be taking the public static `ClassABuilder`, so how to add new member variables in the sub class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an inner public static `ClassBBuilder` builder in `ClassB` that is a subclass of `ClassABuilder`

Comment: That works. Is it some anti-pattern or something that is normally done?

Comment: This is object-oriented design. Then you can simply add to ClassBBuilder the additional member variables that were added to ClassB.

Answer (score 0):

Why constructor of `A` use `Buildler` as a parameter. When user invokes `Builder.create`, builder must initialize default protected constructor of `A`, and then simply set of `A`'s fields. So B you can easily inherit class `B` from `A`

Comment: fields of class A are final so you cannot use setters. The builder needs to be passed in via constructor to set these final fields